# Set the screen saver to 20 minutes

Tags: settings, macos, screensaver

I set 20 minutes in System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver, however the screen saver starts after 5 minutes. I tried to log out and restart the mac with no success.

I should say that after restarting I can see 5 minutes again. So it looks like the settings were not saved.

Comment: what OS are you running on what hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Check the date for the file:
com.apple.screensaver.50A10F0D-581E-5D09-8966-646EE8532C5B.plist in Libary

after you made the time change, it should show the latest date/time.

If not, delete the file.

Comment: Yes, it is the latest time when I update the settings. But still the problem perseveres as I have not changed anything in my system.

Comment: So, it saves your settings! Do you have another program running for screensaver?

Comment: I also found another file called com.apple.screensaver.plist in ~/Library/Preferences and this one does not change. Can I convince the system to use the file that changes?

Comment: I created a symbolic link and will if it works: `ln ./Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.4002120C-60DA-5800-8B83-F4DF0377E8B6.plist ./Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist`

Comment: No, that experiment did not work. What else could I do?

Comment: It is possible your ACLs need to be reset. First use disk utility to reset systems, then use the cmd-r reset password for your user account, but do NOT reset it!!, instead use reset users ACL.